# Obter parte de uma string com Regular Expression - C#

Tags: c#, string, regex

Com base na string "Plano Liberty Empresa +50 - 043-98965-2784(058/PÓS/SMP)", eu preciso obter a parte do "043-98965-2784".

Percebi que no arquivo txt que estou usando, os números seguem o padrão "000-00000-0000".

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria isso

```
var match = Regex.Match(str, @"(\d{3}-\d{5}-\d{4})");
```

O **`\d`** captura qualquer dígito, o número entre chaves diz a quantidade de dígitos que devem ser capturados e o traço é um literal, ou seja, captura um traço.

Código completo:

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var str = "Plano Liberty Empresa +50 - 043-98965-2784(058/PÓS/SMP)";            
        Match match = Regex.Match(str, @"(\d{3}-\d{5}-\d{4})");
        Write(match.Groups[1].Value);
    }
}
```

<sup>[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aZGTIt)</sup>

Comment: Muito bom! Obrigado!